# Como interromper no VisualG?

Tags: algoritmo, visualg, portugol

Boa noite pessoal. Como faço para interromper um comando no visualG?

O que foi pedido:

*Escreva um algoritmo que escreva uma frase na tela até que seja digitada a letra “F” (sem aspas). A frase é a seguinte: A mensagem será interrompida quando a tecla “F” for pressionada.*

O que eu fiz:

```
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 

x,f: caracter

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 

escreval ("A mensagem será interrompida quando a tecla F for pressionada.")
leia (x)
escreval ("Pressione a letra F para interromper a mensagem.")
leia (f)

Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Toguchi, igualmente como a sua outra pergunta, se você não desenvolver um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que demonstre o problema que está passando usa pergunta será FECHADA, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/427226/edit) sua pergunta e coloque um trecho do seu código.

Comment: Estarei editando a pergunta agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a estrutura `enquanto... faca`

Seu código ficará assim:

```
var
continuar: caracter

inicio

// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc...
continuar:="a"
enquanto continuar <> "f" faca
escreval ("A mensagem será interrompida quando a tecla F for pressionada.")
leia (continuar)
fimenquanto
escreval ("A letra F foi pressionada")

fimalgoritmo
```

Como [boas práticas de programação](http://www.devwilliam.com.br/extra/profissional/10-boas-praticas-de-programacao) aconselho a nomear as variáveis corretamente, ou seja, **evite o uso** de variável `x` ou variável `f`

Recomendo a leitura: [MANUAL DO VISUALG](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~bosco.sobral/ensino/ine5201/ApostilaVisuAlg20.pdf)

Comment: Muito obrigado, Luiz Augusto. E obrigado pelo material, será de grande ajuda.

Comment: @toguchi faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja a melhor maneira de agradecer